# React Router v6 > Data Routers: How can I access data from previous data loaders in nested routes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to create an app where on `/animals` routes, you need to be authorized to view any nested routes i.e. `/animals/1/dog`. I have the following code:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path="/" element={<DataLayout />}>
      <Route path="fruits" element={<>fruits</>} />
      <Route path="401" element={<>Unauthorized</>} />
      <Route path="animals/*" element={<Animals />} loader={animalsLoader} id="animals" />
    </Route>
  )
)
```

```
const Animals = () => {
  return (
    <>
      Animals Route
      <Routes>
        <Route path=":animalId">
          <Route path="dog" element={<Dog />} loader={dogLoader} />
          <Route path="cat" element={<Cat />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}
```

When I run this on `/animals/1/dog`, the `dogLoader` isn't called.

Now when I try this:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path="/" element={<DataLayout />}>
      <Route path="fruits" element={<>fruits</>} />
      <Route path="401" element={<>Unauthorized</>} />
      <Route path="animals" loader={animalsLoader} id="animals">
        <Route path=":animalId">
          <Route path="dog" element={<Dog />} loader={dogLoader} />
          <Route path="cat" element={<Cat />} />
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Route>
  )
)
```

It does call the dogLoader but it calls at the same time at animals loader.

I'm expecting in the second piece of code that dogLoader is called after animalLoader with the ability to view the data from animalLoader in dogLoader.

Comment: AFAIK the loaders go to each route, independent from other routes. Can you share these components and loaders as part of your [mcve]?

Comment: The components are just wrappers around `<Outlet />` components and the loaders are just a console.log. There's nothing else to this example.

Comment: Well, then I guess there's nothing else to help debug if nothing has been implemented. Is there some dependency between the two loaders you are expecting? What is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this isn't going to be worked on:
https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/pages/faq#how-can-i-have-a-parent-route-loader-validate-the-user-and-protect-all-child-routes